# How can I correct setting an array element with a sequence error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays, sample, and data. Data will hold the coordinates to an ellipse. All points inside the ellipse will be white and outside will be black.

Now I want to calculate the spatial distance between my sample array and data array (ellipse array) given a certain center of the ellipse (x,y). All of the possible points of the center of the ellipse are stored in another array called center_points.

But I get an error setting array element with a sequence

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import distance 
center_points = []

def combinations(x,y):
    dx = 2
    dy = 2
    return x-dx,y-dy

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        center_points.append(combinations(x,y))

sample = np.random.rand(100,100)

#spatial distance 
spatial_distance = []

data = np.empty((100,100))

def ellipse(x,y):
    if (x**2+y**2/3)>300: 
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def translate(x, y, DX, DY):
    return (x- DX, y - DY)

def rotate(m, n):
    theta = np.radians(45)
    matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
    return np.dot(matrix, (m,n))

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]): 
        data[i][j]= ellipse(i,j)
        data[i][j]= rotate(i,j)
        for a,b in center_points: 
            data.append((translate(i,j,a,b)))
            spatial_distance.append(distance.hamming(data,sample))
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and what line does it occur at? It is usually helpful to include this information pasted in (though the smallest amount necessary to get your issue across.) Minimalism also applies to your code. Any functions or declarations not necessary for the line that is causing the issue should be left out. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: `data.append...` is going to raise an error to, since `data` is an array, not a list.  Apparently your sequence error occurs before that.  What it means is that you are trying to assign a sequence (list, array etc) to an array slot that can only take one number.  What does `rotate` produce?  Another question, why 2 `data[i],[j]` assignments?

Comment: Have you done step by step testing of this code?  Based on the number of errors in the last iteration, I don't think so.  I can't write numpy code without an interactive Python session, where I can test pieces of the code, one by one.